# Inserting all the rows in a List View to a Data Grid View

Tags: vb.net, listview, datagridview

I have a `ListView` that has several items. I want to pass the items to a `DataGridView` but I keep getting this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '14' is not valid for 'index'.
```

This is the code I use:

```
Dim num As Integer
    num = 0
    While (num <= ListView1.Items.Count)
        With ListView1.Items(num)
            Dim lvItem() As String = {.Text, .SubItems(1).Text, .SubItems(2).Text, .SubItems(3).Text, .SubItems(4).Text, .SubItems(5).Text, .SubItems(6).Text} '// get ListView selectedItem.
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(lvItem) '// add it to DataGridView.
        End With

        num = num + 1
    End While
```

Comment: it should be lesser than only since the index starts at zero and the count gives the length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  While `(num < ListView1.Items.Count)` in place of  While `(num <= ListView1.Items.Count)`

Answer (score 0):

If you looping all collection, I will advise to use `For Each`
With that you don't need to worry about indexes and use extra variables for the index number

```
For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
    With item
        Dim lvItem() As String = {.Text, 
                                  .SubItems(1).Text, 
                                  .SubItems(2).Text, 
                                  .SubItems(3).Text, 
                                  .SubItems(4).Text, 
                                  .SubItems(5).Text, 
                                  .SubItems(6).Text} '// get ListView selectedItem.
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(lvItem) '// add it to DataGridView.
    End With        
Next
```